# Creating a round image

Tags: html, css, image

I want to convert square shape image into round shape image but when i applied " border-radius:50px; "
it's giving me oval kind of shape. I tried a lot of things but its just not working. Any help would be appreciated.
This is my HTML code -

`<img class=" skill-row-img" src="images/200w.webp" alt="">`

this is my CSS code -
`.skill-row-img { width: 25%; border-radius: 50% ;}`

[This is how my images are looking on the website .I want them to have a round shape.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPz9e.png)

Comment: Your image dimensions are not right. Set same Width and Height and it will work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does

```css
border-radius: 999999px;
```

suit your need?

The 'better' solution would be to specify your image's width and height explicitly in the CSS, rather than having the browser auto-size it.

```css
.skill-row-img {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border-radius: 200px; /* <-- 50% works here too, because the image is already square so you get a circle rather than an oval*/
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much , It worked. So in order to get image rounded we need to keep its height and width same right ?

Answer (score 0):

Insert bootstrap framework and use **img-fluid** class

```
<img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" alt="placeholder image" class="img-fluid" />
```

Or use the equallent css style:

```
img-fluid {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

and you can also try to set the height and width of the image manually,try to use same width and height!!!!